# Can iPhone Simulator be used with SkyDrive SDK?

Tags: iphone, onedrive

Given that Safari works on the iPhone Simulator.. and that I can't send an email from the iPhone Simulator and require a real iPhone..

..will the SkyDrive SDK work on the iPhone Simulator or will I require a real iPhone to experiment with developing a Skydrive app?

I did try this out using Microsoft's code snippets. This was the result:

```
2012-12-07 17:40:29.875 SkyDriveTest[490:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/..../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/32377034-803E-4913-A13F-08E723DCDA5E/SkyDriveTest.app> (loaded)' with name 'LiveAuthDialog_iPhone''
```

Comment: Why not just give it a try!  But you should really try to test on the device before releasing if you can.  Sometimes there can be slight differences, or the device may lag where the simulator works fine.

Comment: @WolfLink: I have just updated my comments above.

Comment: usually that means it cannot find the file, but from googling it could also be a simulator/device inconsistency.  I would look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155292/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-on-iphone-device

Comment: Also, why is it you cannot test on device?  Is your device too old?  Or do you not have one at all?

Comment: @WolfLink: I cant test on a real device because I haven't renewed my Apple developer license yet.. and I don't want to until I have done more work on my app with the simulator.

Comment: I didn't realise there was an entire sample Xcode project in the SDK archive. I managed to build and run this OK but I honestly don't know if its connecting to Skydrive or not. I'm thinking not as I'm getting told its unavailable at this time.. Looks like I'll have to pay the developer fee to find out for sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the "Live SDK Test Bed" example project to work. Once the client ID was specified it works - so yes, you can use the Skydrive API on the iPhone simulator.