# Emulator vs. Device: NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios

iOS 6.1

Running on device is no problem but when running in emulator I get:

NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Have you experienced anything like this?

Regards
Chris

Comment: Did you check all these [question1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4155292/767730), [question2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5337337/767730) and [question3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5099707/767730)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to instantiate a nib that isn't present. Is the nib included as a project member?

Also Check the Case of name of nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the runtime could not find the right nib file 'Could not load NIB in bundle'

I just did not understand why I would run on the device and not in the emulator. The reason was that I at some point renamed the controller and the NIB file, without deleting and cleaning the app on the device. 
Therefore the old NIB file was probably stil on the device and therefore working, but when running a new instance of the app on the emulator, this is when the error come about.

One could argue that Xcode should have noticed this, but well well :-)

Therefore clean your project when you rename a NIB file.

Happy coding