# App crashes when instantiating view controller from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am implementing time-out action for my app. I referred this stackoverflow thread  [iOS perform action after period of inactivity (no user interaction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085188/ios-perform-action-after-period-of-inactivity-no-user-interaction) and did follow exactly the same approach but my app crashes when it is about to transition to a new view controller over here

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL];

UIViewController *cont = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"abc"];
```

I have given the name abc in my Storyboard file under Storyboard ID. Is there any other way to load a view controller ? What is wrong with this ? Why is my app crashing ?

This is the crash message from console:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle"

I don't have .xib file associated with this controller I am trying to load. I just have abc.h and abc.m files. But in my storyboard file, I have a bunch of view controllers and in there, I have specified the class of one of the view controllers as "abc". Isn't it enough ? Or else, what is the best way to load my view controller ? using segue ?

Comment: Please post your crash log and the error from the console.

Comment: please post the crash message from the debug window

Comment: Updated the post with crash message and more info too

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099707/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbundle and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337337/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding your exception - your storyboard is probably not copied to the main bundle. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155292/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-on-iphone-device).

Also, the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` uses the `Storyboard ID` defined in the Storyboard itself and not the name of the view controller. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867565/what-is-a-storyboard-id-and-how-can-i-use-this) for more information on how to instantiate a specific view controller from a storyboard, or use the `instantiateInitialViewController` if you want to initialize the initial view controller (the one that is pointed by an arrow in your storyboard).

Edit: the exception is raised because of a bug in iOS where storyboards with name modifier, such as `Storyboard_ipad` and `Storyboard_iphone` cause a confusion in an internal iOS mechanism inside `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:]`. The solution is to avoid using this naming convention and possibly write a helper function to choose a storyboard name to load by examining the current device idiom.

Comment: My storyboard is copied into main bundle. I just verified it again.

Comment: 1. Try to clean your project and your project build dir (by pressing alt when cleaning) to make sure the storyboard is copied.
2. Just for kicks - do you happen to have a MainStoryboard~ipad.storyboard file too?

Comment: I tried cleaning it and it didn't help. Yes I have both MainStoryboard_iPhone and MainStoryboard_iPad storyboard files.

Comment: Can you please try and remove the `MainStoryboard_iPad` file, and make a single `MainStoryboard` file? There was a bug (which still exists) regarding `iPhone`/`iPad` naming scheme in storyboard files.