# dismiss nspopover doesn't work

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nspopover

i have a big problem, which i can't solve since a week.
My Situation:

I have an ViewController with a NSTableview and custom cells. in each sell is a nsbutton. if you pressed a button, a nspopover will appear.
but you can close it with the "close"-button, which is assigned to the dismiss-function.
i you pressed the plus button (out of the tableview) the same popover will appear and can close with the "close"-button without problems.

what do i wrong?
i attached the example project via google drive.
thanks for your help:

Download: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8PBtMQt9GdORUxQRXRISWR5dWs

Comment: `NSTableViewController`? And what is the problem?

Comment: sry wrong explanation. View Controller with an NSTableView included. My problem can be read in the first post.

Comment: If you press a button, the popover appears and when you press the close button the popover disappears without problems?

Comment: please download the example - you will see the problem directly

Comment: Aha, the popover doesn't close by itself when you press another button. See [OS X storyboards: using “show” segue without allowing duplicate new windows to show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096257/os-x-storyboards-using-show-segue-without-allowing-duplicate-new-windows-to-s) and [Moving to another view controller in iOS on Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19573982/4244136).

Comment: sry but I think you don't understand the problem. and i don't know how can I explain it better as in post 1

Comment: This is how I read your question: "There's a table view with a button in each cell. The button triggers a popover which can be closed by pressing a close button. There's also a plus button which triggers the same popover.". Which part isn't working?

Comment: the button in the cell can't close the popover with the close button. that is the problem

Comment: The button in the cell uses the close button to close the popover? I think I know what you mean and I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dismissViewController` doesn't work if the view controller doesn't have a presenting view controller (I don't know why). Starting from the downloaded project, make the following changes:

1. Move the `showPopover` action from `CustomCell` to `TableViewController`. Change the type of `sender` to `NSButton`.
2. Present the view controller instead of showing the popover.

   ```
   @IBAction func showPopover(_ sender: NSButton) {
       let vcPopover = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "vcPopover") as! NSViewController
       self.presentViewController(vcPopover, asPopoverRelativeTo : sender.bounds, of : sender, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .transient)
   }
   ```
3. Connect the action of the button in the table view to the Table View Controller and action `showPopover`.

Comment: i do all steps until step 2. but by step 3 i have a problem. i should connect the cell button of my tableview with the function showPopover?